# Unable to remove a JSON item with a null value

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm receiving data from an API where there are 2 `title` and 2 `author` attributes (call them `title_1` and `title_2` for example). I only need one title or author to save to my database, so I regard an item as invalid if both `title_1` and `title_2` is empty.

So here's the problem, it seems to work for the author, but I always end up with one item still being saved despite `title_1` being `null` and `title_2` being `""`. I'm unsure why, but I think maybe there is an issue with how I am parsing the values?

So here is the JSON for item I mentioned:

```
"title_1": null,
"title_2": "",
```

As I said, it successfully splices authors with the same issues. First I am fetching the data (which is received as a string) and parsing it like this:

```
request.get(apiUrl, function(error, response, body) {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        callback(error, data.items);
      }
    });
```

Then I call `removeInvalidItems(data);` later on which does this:

```
function removeInvalidItems(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ( !isValid(data[i].title) && !isValid(data[i].title_2) ) {
      data.splice(i, 1);
    }
    if ( !isValid(data[i].author) && !isValid(data[i].author_2) ) {
      data.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return data;
};
```

It is checking for validity like this:

```
function isValid(attr) {
  if (attr === null || attr === '') {
    return false;
  } else return true;
};
```

Can anyone think of a reason why this item still keeps on passing through this `isValid()` function as valid?

Comment: Just a little thing. You don't need to have the `else` in `else return true as it will return true if the condition is passed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you splice an array like you do (`splice(i, 1)`), your "current index" already points to the next element. Consider the next example. It's "supposed" to remove odd items from the array, but it creates a mess:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 1)
    arr.splice(i, 1);
}

alert(arr);
```

To fix that, when you splice, reduce `i` by 1:

```
function removeInvalidItems(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ( !isValid(data[i].title) && !isValid(data[i].title_2) ) {
      data.splice(i--, 1);
    }
    if ( !isValid(data[i].author) && !isValid(data[i].author_2) ) {
      data.splice(i--, 1);
    }
  }
  return data;
};
```

As a side note, you can greatly simplify your `isValid` function:

```
function isValid(attr) {
  return attr instanceof String && attr.length > 0;
};
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Are you able to explain why that's actually happening when you just use `array.splice(i, 1)` in your example you posted? I have read up on `splice` and used it before so wasn't aware that it would be the `splice` causing the issue!

Comment: @germainelol it's simply because when you remove an item at index i, the item that was at i + 1 now "moves" to i. If you then advance i you're effectively skippiing what was i + 1 before the splice.

Answer (score 1):

When two invalid items follow each other, your loop does not check a second one of them. This happens because you modify an array while looping over it.

Try this in a console to see what's going on.

```
data = [10, 1, 2, 3, 20, 30];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log('checking i=', i, 'data[i]=', data[i]);
    if (data[i] < 5) {
        console.log('removing i=', i, 'data[i]=', data[i]);
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
console.log('data left', data);
```

Instead of modifying array in place, you should probably just [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll remove the `return data` as it should work fine without that.